# What is the time complexity of an index access for an element in an XPath expression used in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

What is the time complexity of the index access for the following XPath expression in XSLT?

```
<xsl:value-of select="User[2]/username"/>
```

1. O(log(n))
2. O(1) or
3. O(n)

I have a **sorted** xml-file with thousands of users which looks like this:

```
<Users>
  <User>
    <idPerson>460</idPerson>
    <username>a_aker01</username>
  </User>
  <User>
    <idPerson>677</idPerson>
    <username>a_aker02</username>
  </User>
  <User>
    <idPerson>1844</idPerson>
    <username>a_aker03</username>
  </User>
  <User>
    <idPerson>2373</idPerson>
    <username>a_aker04</username>
  </User>
</Users>
```

**I am thinking of writing a binary search function in XSLT 2.0 (requiring a fast index access) for a faster search, because**

```
<xsl:variable name="targetId" select="2373" />
<xsl:value-of select="User[idPerson=$targetId]/username"/>
```

**is too slow for my needs.** Does it perform a linear search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time-complexity of `/Users/User[2]` is implementation-specific. Most likely it will be an O(n) linear search, but perhaps there is an implementation out there that is smart enough to do it in O(1) under ideal conditions.

However, why don't you just use `xsl:key` instead of creating a binary search function? (This will work with XSLT 1.0 too.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="user-for-idPerson" match="/Users/User" use="number(idPerson)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="targetId" select="2373" />
    <xsl:value-of select="key('user-for-idPerson', $targetId)/username"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am planning to do the optimization after I've finished everything else, so I haven't had time to test this yet. What would be the complexity of a xsl:key lookup in my case? I can choose between SaxonHE9 and xsltproc.

Comment: `xsl:key` creates an index, so O(1). This is not purely an optimization: it simplifies and abstracts code considerably and can be used to do grouping in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant, when I asked the question, but I am keeping the users in a variable, because they are stored in a helper-document, which is different from the input. According to my tests and research, it is not possible to use this variable in the definition of `xsl:key`, or is there any chance I am wrong? I am thinking of including the content of the users helper-file into my actual input file, to be able to use `xsl:key`.

Comment: `xsl:key` applies to all documents, so you have to use something that changes the context (like `for-each`) to restrict it. See [this other answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13922420/1002469) for an example.

Comment: To be clearer: the `xsl:key` element will index any node (in any document) matching the supplied pattern in `@match`, but the `key()` function only returns matches *in the same document as the current context node*. Hence the need for `for-each` to change the context. Read [the spec for `key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-key) carefully.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Everything is transformed in 2 secs. instead of 30 mins. (before)! =)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the implementation.

Saxon-HE will implement User[idPerson=$targetId] with a linear search, Saxon-EE is likely to build an index.

Both products have time complexity O(n) for numeric filtering of the child axis as in User[2],
but if you use a variable ($User[2]) the access will take constant time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understand you correctly, then storing all users in a variable (<xsl:variable name="users" select="Users/User"/>) would guarantee me an O(1) access on $users[2] (or $users[4000]), with SaxonHE9? If I write a binary search function, I intend to use it only for this particular Users-file, and I hope to be able to search in O(log(n)).

Comment: Yes, that's correct (in general: one can only really tell what the optimizer does when you see the full code).

Answer (score 1):

**In order not to be dependent on particular XSLT processor's implementation, I'd recommend that a key should be used**:

```
<xsl:key name="kUserById" match="User" use="idPerson"/>
```

**Then, when you need to access a `User` by `idPerson`, do just this:**

```
key('kUserById', $targetId)
```

Most XSLT processors implement key indexing efficiently (i.e. using a hash-table), therefore, if `idPerson` is unique for each `User`, the time for access using the `key()` function as shown above is O(1) -- constant.

---

**Regarding your other questions**:

> What is the time complexity of the index access for the following
>   XPath expression in XSLT?
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="User[2]/username"/>
> ```

For the provided XML document it would be most likely O(1), however for a document where `Users` has not only `User` children, but children with other names too, the access time could be O(N) -- imagine that there are 1000 children named `Customer` and the very last two children are named `User`.

> I am thinking of writing a binary search function in XSLT 2.0
>   (requiring a fast index access) for a faster search

The binary search algorithm assumes that the objects to be searched are in an *array* (and in an array the access time by index is O(1)). This assumption is wrong for XSLT/XPath, where there is still no *array* data structure.

Some XSLT processors (like Saxon) may implement sequences in an efficient way (using vectors) with time for access O(1), but many of them don't do this.

Therefore, to access:

```
 $seq[$mid]
```

generally takes O(N), and the binary search algorithm applied on such a sequence is O(N^2).

Comment: Thanks for the general and concrete case explanation. I don't mind sticking to a particular xslt-processor and my xml-file is sorted according to 'idPerson' and not going to change. I was wondering if given these preconditions a real binary search would be possible. It seems to me that it is (with SaxonHE9). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ivo, Dr. Michael Kay is the authoritative source. In my experience, Saxon doesn't implement all sequences as vectors -- this means that for some sequences the BS would be fast but for some it may be very slow. If there is a guaranteed way of producing a vector-based sequence, then I'd use BS, otherwise I am not convinced in its utility. Anyway, why don't you stick with keys, where possible? Or, if you can use XSLT 3.0, one can use the map data structure for extremely efficient search for a key by its value.

Comment: `the binary search algorithm applied on such a sequence is O(N^2)`
Just for the record, Isn't it O(n*log(n))? O(log(n)) lookups and O(n) cost for each lookup (all worst case). I just couldn't figure out why O(n²).

Comment: @Ivo, Yes, you are right. But O(N*log(N)) of course id bigger than O(N) -- which one gets with simple, sequential search of the sequence.