# Checking values of 2 different xml documents against each other

Tags: xml, xslt, nextsibling

I'm working with 2 XML documents, and trying to get a value from one document into the other if a  variable is matched. The first XML document is a converted spreadsheet formatted like:

```
<Doc1>
    <row>
      <cell>VA15</cell>
      <cell>wr23</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>VA45</cell>
      <cell>wr27</cell>
    </row>        <row>
      <cell>VA78</cell>
      <cell>wr24</cell>
    </row>
</Doc1>
```

The second XML document is a longer one inside of which there's an `id` element matching one part of the spreadsheet:

```
<Doc2>
 <p> text text text
  <id>wr23</id>
 </p>
</Doc2>
```

I'm trying with my xslt transformation to test to see if the `id` element matches the value of a `cell` in doc1 it pulls the value of the preceding `cell`. In this case I'd like the xslt transformation to output "VA15". I've tried various permutations of the following code without success, does anyone have any ideas?

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('Doc1.xml')//row">
   <xsl:if test="/cell=//id'">
     <xsl:value-of select="/preceding-sibling::cell"/>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: `Doc1.xml` is invalid XML. Just a typo?

Comment: Yeah, I had a > where there should've been a <. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:for-each select="document('Doc1.xml')//row">
>    <xsl:if test="/cell=//id'">
>      <xsl:value-of select="/preceding-sibling::cell"/>
>    </xsl:if>
> </xsl:for-each>
> ```

A number of problems:

1. None of the two documents has a top element named `cell` -- instead of absolute expression you must use a relative one:

.....

```
cell = //id
```

and

```
  preceding-sibling::cell
```

because a document node doesn't have siblings.

.2. The document that has element named `cell` doesn't have elements named `id`. When an XPath expression references more than one document, all documents but one must be explicitly referenced. With all corrections, your code becomes something like this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="vthisDoc" select="/"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="document('Doc1.xml')//row">
     <xsl:if test="cell=$vthisDoc//id'">
       <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::cell"/>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

**Finally**, all this can be written shortly as:

```
<xsl:copy-of select=
 "document('Doc1.xml')//row[cell=$vthisDoc//id]/preceding-sibling::cell[1]/text()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Dimitre's answer, you can abstract this "look up an IDREF" pattern out into a separate template using `key()` (for fast lookups) and `call-template`:

**id-lookup.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="id-lookup-doc">Doc1.xml</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="id-to-value-doc" select="document($id-lookup-doc)"/>

<xsl:key name="value-for-id"
    match="/Doc1/row/cell[1]"
    use="../cell[2]" />


<xsl:template name="value-for-id">
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <!-- for-each is just to change the context
         to limit results from key() to the lookup document -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$id-to-value-doc">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('value-for-id', $id)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**replace-id-with-value.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:import href="id-lookup.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="id">
    <val>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="value-for-id">
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="text()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </val>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you run this through an xslt processor, you get the document with all `<id>` elements replaced with `<val>` and the corresponding value.

Using `xsltproc`, you would run this like so:

```
xsltproc id-with-value.xsl Doc2.xml myOtherDoc.xml
```

You can even change the lookup document using an xslt param:

```
xsltproc --stringparam id-lookup-doc MyOtherSetOfIdsAndValues.xml id-with-value.xsl Doc2.xml
```

Whatever XSLT processor you are using will have some way of specifying a template param.